# Nim enumerate function like Python

Tags: enumerate, nim-lang

Learning [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/) and I like it resemblence of Python (but fast). In Python I can do this:

```
item_index = [(idx, itm) for idx, itm in enumerate(row)]
```

Im looking for a way to **enumerate** a Nim sequence so I would write this:

```
item_index = lc[(idx, itm) | (idx, itm <- enumerate(row))]
```

Does this functionality exist? I'm sure you could create it, maybe with a proc, template or macro it but I'm still very new, and these seem hard to create myself still. Here is my attempt:

```
iterator enumerate[T](s: seq[T]): (int, T) =
    var i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        yield (i, s[i])
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm a newbie with nim, and I'm not really sure what you want, but...
If you use two variables in a `for` statement, you will get the index and the value:

```
for x, y in [11,22,33]:
  echo x, " ", y
```

Gives:

```
0 11
1 22
2 33
```

HTH.

Comment: Some background why this works: When Nim's sees a for loop with two loop variables, it tries to call `pairs` on the given expression. The `pairs` operator is defined for `openarray` in [system.nim](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#pairs.i,openArray[T]) and it does [exactly](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/9ca56863982fd623739e36adbc1455a2d5c5c8e7/lib/system.nim#L2142) what `enumerate` does.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work for all iterables. For example, if you try to do this with `start .. end` or with `countup(start, end, step)` you will get a `wrong number of variables` error.

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs why would you do that?, OP is trying to iterate an array.